# Visual Studio Code: Java does not execute unless package statement is commented out

Tags: java, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

When opening any Java project, or maven project, new or old, Java throws "Error: Could not find or load main class App" at runtime. Java will only run if "package foo;" is commented out i.e. "//package foo;".

I am using the code runner extension, which works with every other language. It runs as expected in java if the package statement is excluded or commented out.

This is able to be replicated in every new java program created or opened inside VS Code, even projects created in IntelliJ (Which run as expected) and opened in VS Code.

Environment:

Operating System: Mac OSX Mojave 10.14.4 
JDK version: 1.8.0_202 
Visual Studio Code version: 1.33.0 
Java extension version: 0.6.0

I could never get my java code to run inside VS Code, until I removed the package statement (commented it out). Once the package statement is removed my code runs as expected, but has a 'problem' inside VS Code saying "The declared package "" does not match the expected package "app"Java(536871240)"

```
//package app;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello Java");
    }
}
```

[Example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVs7z.png)
[Example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0SOH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you've already setup the JDK environment in the right way
2. Try to clean your workspace:[Clean the workspace directory](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/Troubleshooting#clean-the-workspace-directory)
3. Make sure to reload a new workspace after you finished all the above steps.

I fixed by using the above steps when I have this error. Hope it can also works on your side.

Comment: Nope, did not work. Still receiving the same error. What do you mean by "Make sure you've already set up the JDK environment in the right way"?

Comment: @grantjay I mean you can try to set java.home in your configuration file and see if it helps. Well, actually I think this is a dependency lookup problem and it actually should work. Have you also tried to restart the machine first?